# Looking for better way to get coverage for standalone application with dotCover console

Tags: dotcover

I am trying to implement following scenario for standalone application(AUT):

1. start dotcover
2. start application
3. do same actions
4. close application
5. repeat 2-4
6. repeat 2-4
7. finally stop dotcover and collect report

Actually I have automated UI test for the AUT, but they start and stop the app few times while doing different tests.

My current solution is to modify the way tests start app in order to use dotCover and then at the end to merge reports created after all test is finished. However this is not very good solution.

Any ideas if above scenario is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found that for some application this may work

```
(1)
dotcover.exe cover-everything --StartInstance=123 --Output=out.dcvr

(7) 
dotcover.exe send --Instance=123 --Command=GetSnapshotAndKillChildren
```

It worked for UI app

It does not work for console app. But same console app (sometimes) works with "dotcover cover". Bad things is you need to pass all parameters and collect all outputs via dotcover - not good